# Распределить место

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

http://jsfiddle.net/s288S/

```css
#block {
  background: #cccccc;
  padding: 15px;
}
.user {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 56px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
  <div class="user">
    <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
</div>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы например в первом ряду не оставалось столько много места в конце, а как-то само всё распределялось? Т.е в первом ряду, в конце, должно остаться столько места, сколько и в начале первого ряда?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/s288S/2/

```css
#block {
  background: #cccccc;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
.user {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 56px;
  text-align: center;
}
.user-list {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="block">
  <div class="user-list">
    <div class="user">
      <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
    <div class="user">
      <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
    <div class="user">
      <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
    <div class="user">
      <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
    <div class="user">
      <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
    <div class="user">
      <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
    <div class="user">
      <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
    <div class="user">
      <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
    <div class="user">
      <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
    <div class="user">
      <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
    <div class="user">
      <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
    <div class="user">
      <img src="http://cs540108.vk.me/c7003/v7003079/374b/53lwetwOxD8.jpg">Павел</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @lvil, как вариант, но центрирование не подойдёт. Некрасиво.